# What should I replace the hibernate deprecated @TypeDef and @Type annotations by?

Tags: java, hibernate, deprecated

I've just upgraded the version I use for Hibernate to 5.6.1 and it seems it's now deprecating some Type-related annotations:

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)


@Type(type = "json")
```

I found no documentation as to what to do except that

> 6.0 will introduce a new series of type-safe annotations to serve the same purpose

Our quality guidelines forces us to try and solve every warning and as such I would like to replace these annotations by a non deprecated use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems there is no replacement until Hibernate 6. [Type and also TypeDef](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14935) was marked as deprecated to mark it as removed in version 6, but so far not replacement exists. The ideology here is that deprecated does not indicate that already a new version exists, which might be not an intuitive meaning for most developers.

This was reverted now in the current 5.6.3-Final version series.

Answer (score 14):

From this

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
 
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)
public class EntityName {
 
 @Type(type = "json")
 private propertyName
```

to in hibernate 6

```
import jakarta.persistence.Convert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
 
 
@Convert(attributeName = "entityAttrName", converter = StringJsonUserType.class)
public class EntityName {
 
 
 @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
 private propertyName
```

Comment: I'll add that `@Convert` is not necessary for ex. if you property is a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

This deprecation has been reverted in Hibernate 5.6.3-Final

Comment: I'd like to accept both answers but StackOverflow prevents me from doing so. In any case your answer combined to k_o_'s fully closes this question. Thanks. There is indeed no replacement and they did remove the deprecation as a patch because "it was wrong" :)

Comment: In Hibernate 6, `@TypeDef` is removed and `@Type` is changed. Therefore it's not clear how to map a PostgreSQL enum type. I asked a question here — https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/514.